# Using Nelder-Mead algorithm for minimizing the sum of absolute deviations from the residuals

Tags: r, regression, estimation, optimization

How can I minimize the sum of absolute deviations from the residuals using the function optim() with the Nelder-Mead algorithm for creating the estimation in R?

[image]

```
tlad <- function(y = "farm", x = "land", data="FarmLandArea.csv")
{
  dat <- read.csv(data)
  fit<-lm(dat$farm~dat$land)
  #....what is func
  optim(fit$coefficients,func)

  return(fit)
}
```

Comment: Is this a class assignment?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @QuantIbex What are the beta1 and beta2 that I should feed into optim() function?

Comment: The parameters fed into `optim` are starting values for the optimization. The [OLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) estimates as you did are probably not a bad choice.

Answer (score 4):

This question seems to be a [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question so for the moment I'll just provide hints.

1. Write a function, say `sum.abs.dev`, taylored for `optim` that computes the sum of absolute deviations for a given set of parameter values (and data). Note that the function's first argument should be the vector of parameters you're willing to minimize, that is $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$. It should return a scalar with the sum of absolute deviations (see `?optim`).
2. Use the `optim` function with appropriate parameters, including your `sum.abs.dev` function, initial values for the vector of regression parameters, the data, and the optimization method.

Please explain where you're stuck and show what you've done so far if you would like additional information.

Comment: My problem is that I am unsure what is the function I should feed into optim() to have beta1 and beta2 as result. Please take a look at updated question.

Comment: The function fed into `optim` is the one I called `sum.abs.dev` in my answer.
It should return the value of $Q(\beta_0, \beta_1)$ for inputs $\boldsymbol{\beta} =(\beta_0$, $\beta_1)$, $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, and $\boldsymbol{y} = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.

Comment: ok now I guess it's more clear. I work on it and let you know